# What are the differences between Blue coat ProxySG and Cisco Ironport?

Tags: security, cisco, proxy, ironport, bluecoat

What are the main differences between ProxySG and Cisco's Ironport Appliances?

I already found out:

Cisco's Ironport:
- is only available as a scalable Hardware Appliance (not Virtual)
- high funcionality
- very expensive

Blue coat's ProxySG:
- also available as a Virtual Appliance
- also high functionality (but it is higher than Cisco's ?)
- very expensive (I didn't find any Prices, which one is more expensive?)